# How to stop 0 amount transactions in ERC20 contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

In my contract code I have implemented checks to stop 0 amount transactions inside Transfer method:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) isRunning validAddress public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value,"Insufficient balance.");
    require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to],"Pass a correct value."); 
}
```

But its not working as expected, I tried to sent 0 ethers to a test address and its sent without any contract error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about transferring Ether or tokens? Your code looks like token transfer function but you are testing it by sending Ether?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I want to stop 0 ether transactions and 0 token transfer as well. So nobody can send 0 ether to contract, and can't send 0 tokens to other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to stop 0 Ether transfers. I'm not sure if clients would typically even allow sending 0 Ethers, but even if they do, it doesn't hurt anyone if your contract receives 0 Ether. You just get 0 Ethers in the contract, they pay for the transaction and that's it, nothing else happens.

For refusing 0 token transfers, you can use something like what @Eli Drion wrote:

```
require(_value > 0, "Enter valid token amount");
```

But basically you're already doing this with your line (if you remove the equal sign):

```
require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to],"Pass a correct value.");
```

Comment: Are messages supported on requires? I thought that was for a later implementation

Comment: They just added them. And as the OP used them, I assume he uses a recent version :) https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases

Comment: Sweet! I'm running my contracts on Ganache, I wonder what I have to update to include it, would changing the Pragma version be enough? Do I have to way for the Ganache team to implement it? And where would the error message show up exactly?

Answer (score 2):

How did you implement it? I don't see it in your code.

Simply add

```
require(_value > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you mention in your comment that :

> I want to stop 0 ether transactions and 0 token transfer as wel

1.so as the other friends have answered you will add to your transfer function the following verification

```
require(_value > 0);
```

2. in order to stop 0 ether transactions :

in you payable function (deposit) add

```
require (msg.value > 0);
```